# Access forbidden (403) if access file via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, apache

On the index page i have created a form (not in HTML but via JavaScript) and has enclosed it in a function which is called after certain conditions. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
    function next_page()
{
var card="Some values ab,xy";
var form = document.createElement("form");
    input = document.createElement("input");

form.action = "preview_card.php";
form.method = "post"

input.name = "card_data";
input.value = card;
form.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}
```

but the problem is, when the function is called "Forbidden" message is shown as:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /preview_card.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

but if  i directly goto preview_card.php, the page is displayed.

Why is the access forbidden when the file is called by a JS file but if i directly input the link into browser, it shows up.

Comment: Make sure `preview_card.php` is in the same directory as your index file.

Comment: It is in the same directory

Comment: Check your `error_log` in that case for more error details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your server denies ajax (X-Requested-With) requests. Try set **Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type** header on server-side.

By the way - why you not using jQuery?

```
$.post(
    '/preview_card.php',
    {
        card_data: "Some values ab, xy"
    },
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        /* some actions with response here */
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `preview_card.php` accepts currently no `POST` request. In regular case, if you enter an url to your address bar, your browser performs a `GET` request. Try to change your `form.method` to `"get"`.

Comment: but the code works on local server, i am getting problem on if i put it on remote server, but anyways, i will try GET method too

Comment: I tried using GET too, but it is giving me same error, it seems it is not much about variable passing, but more about some .htaccess config file